# How can I create a directory in a directory getting its name as input?

Tags: bash

If for example I get as input `filename` and `dirname` and I want to create new directory with name `filename` at `dirname`.

How can I do it?

I tried to do it with `mkdir` but it's creates the directory only in the current directory (and doesn't allow me to choose how to create the new directory).

Comment: `mkdir -p "$dirname/$filename"`?

Comment: @user000001 Can you explain why I need here the flag `p`?

Comment: `-p` tells `mkdir` to create any leading directories if they don't already exist. For example, if `foo` doesn't already exist, then `mkdir foo/bar` will fail, but `mkdir -p foo/bar` will create `foo` before it tries to create `bar`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure fully if you are looking for this, you could try it and let me know if this helps you.

```
cat script.ksh
filename="$1"
directory="$2"

if [ ! -d "$directory" ]
then
        mkdir -p "$directory/$filename"
else
        echo "There seems to be directory already present, please enter some other directory name."
fi
```

From `man mkdir`:

> ```
>    -p, --parents
>           no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
> ```

Comment: Hye, can you explain what are you tried to do with `presence`?

Comment: @Software_t, doing a check either given directory by person as an argument to script is present or not, if yes then it will throw a message you should run it like `script.ksh second_directory  first_dirctory" in case `first_directory` is present it will not run then, let me know in case you have any queries on same.

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this. Just test for the directory with `if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then `mkdir -p "$directory/$filename"; else ...; fi`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you :) It's working , now I understand it.